# How do I deploy a .inf based driver?

Tags: windows-installer, driver

I would like to deploy a .inf based USB driver with my installer.

I guess the .inf needs to be placed in `%SystemRoot%\inf`, but there is also a .cat (WHQL certification I guess?), and .sys files.  What do I do with those?

**EDIT:** Resolved, thanks to the helpful answers.
I was able to P/Invoke the function, so I have a post-install action which runs the following code:

```
namespace DriverPackageInstallAction
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("DIFXApi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern Int32 DriverPackagePreinstall(string DriverPackageInfPath, Int32 Flags);

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            DirectoryInfo assemblyDir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
            DirectoryInfo installDir = assemblyDir.Parent;

            int result = DriverPackagePreinstall(installDir.FullName + @"\Driver\XYZ.inf", 0);
            if (result != 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Driver installation failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start by reading about [SetupAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550855.aspx) and [DIFx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544838.aspx). The Windows Driver Kit includes [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541313.aspx) of both, including a DIFx-based merge module and a DIFx-based WiX library. The source for the command-line [devcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541193.aspx) utility, which is based on SetupAPI, is also included in the WDK samples.

Comment: correct links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550855.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544838.aspx

Comment: @Dercsár: thanks, I'll update all 4 links to point to the new locations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try asking the shell to install it for you:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 YOUR_FILE.inf
```

But I'm 100% sure there's a better way...

Comment: Well, it worked on my computer when I tried it... I guess your computer is just different...