# How to find the drive letter of an USB mass storage drive using VID and PID in C#?

Tags: c#, usb

We design a **USB**  **MSD** product, for that we need to write a **C#** application which will do some processing on the files stored in the memory.

> Can anybody advise me,how to detect whether an **USB** device with a
>   particular **VID+PID** is connected to the computer and if so, what is
>   the drive letter(Or root drive path)?

I could able to find examples to detect whether a particular(**VID+PID**) **USB** device is present or not.
And also could able to find example programs to detect the available removable drives and what is the path...etc.

Is there any example programs in **C#** combining these together?

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going suggest using a wrapper around the SetupApi but it looks like someone else has already put together a really good answer. [DEVCON.EXE (driver tool) and OpenVPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167544/devcon-exe-driver-tool-and-openvpn?answertab=votes#tab-top)