# How do I use WiX to deploy an INF-based USB driver

Tags: wix, driver, inf

This question could be considered a duplicate of:

[How do I deploy a .inf based driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677686/how-do-i-deploy-a-inf-based-driver)

Except that I want to do that entirely in the installer, not with a separate program.

There's supposed to be an example downloadable here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163212.aspx

But there's no download link on that page.

The driver structure is very simple, just an inf and an sys.  I've tried this:

```
  <Directory Id='SystemFolder' Name='System32'>
    <Directory Id='DriversFolder' Name='Drivers'/>
  </Directory>
```

...

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DriversFolder">
  <Driver Id="cyusb" Guid="*">
    <File Id="cyusb.inf" Source="..\Includes\cyusb.inf" />
  </Driver>
  <Driver Id="cyusb_sys" Guid="*">
    <File Id="cyusb.sys" Source="..\Includes\cyusb.sys" />
  </Driver>
</DirectoryRef>
```

with the 'wixdifxappextension.dll' and difxapp_x86 both included as references to my project, and the 'driver' tag isn't recognized.  If I use 'component' instead of 'driver', then the resulting file isn't actually recognized as a driver, and I have to do a manual installation.

What am I doing wrong here?  Or will I have to write yet another program to make this installer work?  This is in Wix 3.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the manual, [`<Driver>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html) should be under [`<Component>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html), and your Wix should look something like:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DriversFolder" FileSource="..\Includes\">
  <Component Id="MyDriver" Guid="[PUT GUID]">
    <Driver Legacy='yes' />
    <File Id="cyusb.inf" Vital="yes" />
    <File Id="cyusb.sys" Vital="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

More information from [this guy's blog](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/installing-filter-drivers-with-difxapp-and-a-wix-v3-msi/)

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem. The following worked for me.

Added to the project 2 references:

- WixDifxAppExtension
- difxapp_x64.wixlib

Inside the `Wix` node of .wxs file, I added the attribute:

```
xmlns:difxapp='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DifxAppExtension'
```

Looks like it needs to refer and use the `difxapp` namespace.

Inside the `Component` that includes the `.inf` file, I added:

```
<difxapp:Driver PlugAndPlayPrompt="no"/>
```

Comment: `WixDifxAppExtension` and `difxapp_x64.wixlib` could be found in `Program Files (x86)\Wix ToolSet v.3.11\bin` (use Add Reference dialog of Visual Studio)