# Wix drivers install?

Tags: xml, wix, driver

Morning you beautiful people!

My sysadmin as decided that we should do everything with .msi and I am stuck trying to make a wix project to install .inf based drivers.

I saw some post explaining briefly how to do this like:

[WIX Installer for a INF based printer Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962334/wix-installer-for-a-inf-based-printer-driver)

However, I would really like a complete example (whole slns file) to make me understand the structure I need to do. Right now it doesn't even compile. Here's the content of my product.wxs (PS:Sorry for the formatting mess):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="DriversTest" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" 
       Manufacturer="" UpgradeCode="8caa9c0d-c692-4aa6-9267-a13577f51cb6">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" 
      InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is 
        already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="DriversTest" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="DriversTest" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

   <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the 
       ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources 
            here. -->
        <!-- </Component> -->
         </ComponentGroup>
       </Fragment>
      </Wix>

           <Component Id="google-usb" Guid="{4fba0d21-64bb-458d-9b78-23aed7a39d14}" 
        Directory = "C:\drivers-folder\google">
         <difx:Driver Legacy='yes' />
          <File Id="Catalog" Name="androidwinusba64.cat" 
            Source="androidwinusba64.cat" />
            <File Id="Info" Name="android_winusb.inf" KeyPath="yes" 
            Source="android_winusb.inf" />
        </Component>
             <Component Id="google-usb" Guid="{4fba0d21-64bb-458d-9b78-23aed7a39d14}" Directory = "C:\drivers-folder\google">
           <difx:Driver Legacy='yes' />
            <File Id="Catalog" Name="androidwinusba64.cat" Source="androidwinusba64.cat" />
     <File Id="Info" Name="android_winusb.inf" KeyPath="yes" Source="android_winusb.inf" />
            </Component>
```

I then proceed to call as a batch file this:

@ECHO OFF

ECHO ------------Generating drivers install----------------

"%WIX%bin\candle" -ext WixDifxAppExtension *.wxs -o obj\
"%WIX%bin\light" -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixDifxAppExtension *.wixobj difxapp_x64.wixlib -o bin\google-usb.msi

PAUSE

Which fails because of this error:

Product.wxs
C:\test\DriversTest\DriversTest\DriversTest\Product.wxs(32) : error CNDL0104 : Not a valid source file; detail: There are multiple root elements. Line 32, position 2.
light.exe : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file '*.wixobj' with type 'Source'.
Press any key to continue . . .

I could really use a hand. I am a total noob at this and I think I need some guidance. I suck at XML.

Comment: Some **quick links**: [Driver deployment is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845307/129130). [Driver installation with WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820791/129130).

Comment: I'm close I can feel it! Your link helped a lot. I updated my code and I have only one error left:

The Component element contains an unhandled extension element 'difx:Driver'.  Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DifxAppExtension' namespace has been provided. 

Got an idea how to do this?

Comment: [Check the github link to a sample there](https://github.com/kobykahane/NpEtw/blob/e4854ee500214d11b435eaba03d5c52cc59396e9/NpEtwSetup/Product.wxs). See the namespace added at the top? You probably need a dll reference too - which you add at the Visual Studio project level. Not sure.

Comment: Axiom, that was a very rushed comment, did you get a heartbeat going?

Comment: I'm excitable and I tried to get this working for 3 days now.

Comment: Allright... everything is declared properly but I still get a build error.
The Component element contains an unhandled extension element 'difx:Driver'.  Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DifxAppExtension' namespace has been provided. Drivers-test2 C:\test\Drivers-test2\Drivers-test2\Product.wxs 56

Comment: I haven't tested but isn't that just a matter of right clicking the WiX project and add a reference to whatever DLL that is required in **`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin"`**? Maybe try **`WixUtilExtension.dll`** and **`WixDifxAppExtension.dll`**. If that does not work try adding more?

Comment: [**Sample on youtube.com for how to add reference**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wyUxQux7xY&t=610)

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is badly formed. The root element `<Wix>` should be the last tag closed at the bottom but it is closed quite a way before the end of the file. This is why the compiler is complaining about "multiple root elements".

If you have an editor that understands XML and does syntax highlighting/coloring, then that will probably help you fix up the file so that everything is inside the `<Wix>` element.

Here is an example of a well-formed Wix source file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIRECTORY"/>
    <ComponentGroup Id="cgDeviceLayer" Directory="INSTALLDIRECTORY">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="cgPostSharp"/>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="cgReactiveAscom" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="cgPostSharpAspects" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="cgNLog" />
      <Component Id="cmpDeviceControlLayer" Guid="*" Win64="no">
        <File Id="filDeviceLayerAssembly"
              Source="$(var.DeviceLayer.TargetPath)"
              KeyPath="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              Assembly=".net"
              AssemblyApplication="filDeviceLayerAssembly" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Note: this isn't a full product definition, it is one file taken from a large installer to serve as an example showing how all of the content should be inside the `<Wix>` tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it another go. If it doesn't work, we will just use WSUS to push our drivers.... sucks but what can I do?