# PInvoke UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices with GetLastError -536870347

Tags: c#, driver, pinvoke

I've tried invoking UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices three different ways. Here they are:

```
 [DllImport("newdev.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(
        IntPtr hwndParent,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string HardwareId,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string FullInfPath,
        uint InstallFlags,
        ref bool bRebootRequired);

    [DllImport("newdev.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(
        [In, Optional]  IntPtr hwndParent,
        [In] string HardwareId,
        [In] string FullInfPath,
        [In] uint InstallFlags,
        [Out, Optional] bool bRebootRequired
        );

    [DllImport("newdev.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(
        IntPtr hwndParent,
        string HardwareId,
        string FullInfPath,
        uint InstallFlags,
        ref bool bRebootRequired
        );
```

Regardless of which of these I call, the returned result is false, and the following call to `Marshall.GetLastWin32Error()` gives an error code of -536870347. I've searched and searched and not found any such error code.

I feel like the problem is with the way I'm defining the function because I can pass nonsensical parameters to my call to `UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices()` and I still get the same error code.

The previous calls leading up to this work fine, I'm using pinvoked calls to `SetupDiGetClassDevsW()`, `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()`, `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()` and `SetupCopyOEMInf()` and they all act in the expected ways.

Can someone tell me what this error means, or what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638257/error-using-windows-driver-kit-driverpackagepreinstall

Comment: I'd call that related. I searched before posting, I promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> gives an error code of -536870347

Always convert such large numbers to hex.   You'll get 0xE0000235. That googles very well, it is `ERROR_IN_WOW64`.  Or in other words, you cannot make SetupDi calls from a 32-bit program on the 64-bit version of Windows.

Right-click your EXE Project, Properties, Build tab.  Remove the jitter forcing so it runs as AnyCPU.  Untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option if you see it.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: Thank you Hans! I had no idea about the hex conversion (obviously) - very useful piece of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
    [DllImport("NewDev.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices")]
    [SecurityCritical]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal extern static bool UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(IntPtr hwndParent,
                                                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]String szHardwordID,
                                                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]String szINFName,
                                                                uint installFlags, IntPtr bRebootRequired);
```